# Event handling function not working with `this` keyword

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web, frontend

Why can't I get data from `this` keyword in event handler and how can it be fixed?

```
twittyApp.factory('Unshown', function () {
function Unshown() {
    this.allIsLoaded = false;
    this.loading = false;
    this.firstTime = true;
    this.scrollMarker = 100;
    this.loadedUnshownPages = 0;
    this.timeLineHiader = $cookies.get("lastReadedTweetId");
}
window.onscroll = function () {
     //why here this.scrollMarker is undefined?
};
return Unshown;
});
```

Comment: Put window.onscroll inside the Unshown function

Comment: How you accessing this.scrollMarker inside onscroll?

Comment: 'var scroled .......
                if (this.scrollMarker > scrolled && !this.loading && !this.allIsLoaded) {
                    this.loading = true;}'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this changes

```
twittyApp.factory('Unshown', function() {

    var fact = {};

    function Unshown() {
        this.allIsLoaded = false;
        this.loading = false;
        this.firstTime = true;
        this.scrollMarker = 100;
        this.loadedUnshownPages = 0;
        this.timeLineHiader = $cookies.get("lastReadedTweetId");
    }

    var objUnShown = new Unshown();
    window.onscroll = function() {
        objUnShown.scrollMarker // aceess scrollmarker
    };

fact.Unshown =objUnShown;


    return fact.Unshown;
});
```

First you need to create an object of `UnShown` class then you can access their property.

EDIT 2 : 
if you want to create object whenever you want, you can do it in this way.

```
twittyApp.factory('Unshown', function() {

        var fact = {};

        function Unshown() {
             ..
        }

        window.onscroll = function() {
            objUnShown.scrollMarker // aceess scrollmarker
        };

    fact.Unshown =Unshown;


        return fact;
    });

 /// in controller do this.

 var objUnshown = new Unshown.Unshown()
```

Comment: that's not true, you do not have to create an UnShown object, you just have to keep track of the "this" variable. thats all

Comment: Please paste the error

Comment: @riyaj-khan your solution works, this coment was for solution with this, but I got another unexpetced result Unshown() in not constructor, in other controller, but it isn't problem. Thank you and good luck!

Comment: Oo, now this handler works on every page, it isn't good, it crushed in login page and after that not work on main page.

Comment: What's the point of this `fact` object?

Answer (score 0):

By using the `this` keyword inside the `Unshown` functions, you are setting properties of that function object. To access those properties outside the function, use the property accessor on the function object reference.

```
twittyApp.factory('Unshown', function () {
function Unshown() {
    this.allIsLoaded = false;
    this.loading = false;
    this.firstTime = true;
    this.scrollMarker = 100;
    this.loadedUnshownPages = 0;
    this.timeLineHiader = $cookies.get("lastReadedTweetId");
}
window.onscroll = function () {
     //this.scrollMarker is undefined
     //
     //Use property accessor
     console.log(Unshown.scrollMarker);
};
return Unshown;
});
```

---

### Using `window.onscroll` in AngularJS

Using `window.onscroll` is the [Older way to register event listeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Older_way_to_register_event_listeners).

In AngularJS, event listeners are added using [Angular's jqLite](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element#angular-s-jqlite).

```
var windowElem = angular.element($window);

windowElem.on('scroll', function scrollListener (event) {
    console.log(event);
};
```

Be sure to add `$window` to the list of injectables for the factory function.